# Jsx does not show props properly

Tags: reactjs, filter, jsx

I am learning react by creating an app, but I have a strange problem in my code, could someone please point out the error? thanks

```
 test=()=>{
        console.log('filtered card: ',this.state.cards.filter(c=>c.id===this.state.idToDelete)[0].name)

    }
```

when I use this function to test the line of code, it works fine and shows all of the name properly when ever I click but when I apply the line to render so I can have the name so to put in my Jsx it gives me error?

```
    const warningCard=this.state.idToDelete && this.state.cards.filter(c=>c.id===this.state.idToDelete)[0].name.toUpperCase()
    return(
        <div>

        <button onClick={this.test}>test</button>
        <button onClick={()=>this.setState({showForm:!this.state.showForm})}>form</button>
        <button onClick={()=>this.setState({showEditForm:false})}>close edit from</button>

        <h2>you have {this.state.cards.length} {card}</h2>

        {this.state.showWarning && 
        <div>
            <h2>ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE THIS {warningCard} CARD?</h2>
```

this is the picture

[image]

all the cards show their names correctly when I use console.log and comment out the warningCard, but when I add the warningCard line in i have this error

[image]

this is my full component if it may help

```
import React from 'react';
import CardList from './cardList';
import CardForm from './cardForm';

    class FlashCardMainPage extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state={
                cards:[
                    {...},
                    {...},
                    {...}],
                nextId:3,
                showForm:false,
                showEditForm:false,
                cardToEdit:{},
                showWarning:false,
                confirm:false,
                idToDelete:''
            }
        }

        onCardClick=(id)=>{
            const {cards}=this.state
            const newCardsState=this.state.cards.map((c)=> c.id===id ? {...c,showInfo:!c.showInfo} : c)
            this.setState({cards:newCardsState})
        }

        deleteCard=(id)=>{
            this.setState({showWarning:true})
            this.setState({idToDelete:id})
        }

        editCard=(id)=>{
            const cardToEdit = this.state.cards.filter(c=>c.id===id)
            this.setState({cardToEdit, showEditForm:true})
        }

        onFormSubmit=(cardFromSubmit)=>{
            const newCard={id:this.state.nextId,...cardFromSubmit}
            this.setState({
                cards:[...this.state.cards,newCard], 
                nextId:this.state.nextId+1,
                cardToEdit:{},
                showForm:false
            })
        }

        onEditCardSubmit=(editedCard)=>{
            this.setState({showEditForm:false})
            const cards=this.state.cards.map((c)=>c.id===this.state.cardToEdit[0].id?c={id:c.id,...editedCard}:c)
            this.setState({cards})
        }

        onCloseForm=()=>{
            this.setState({showForm:false, showEditForm:false})
        }

        test=()=>{
            console.log('filtered card: ',this.state.cards.filter(c=>c.id===this.state.idToDelete)[0].name)

        }

        onConfirm=(pass)=>{
            const check=pass
            if(pass){
                const cards=this.state.cards.filter(c=>c.id!==this.state.idToDelete)
                this.setState({cards, showWarning:false}) 
            }else
                this.setState({showWarning:false})
        }

        render(){
            const card=this.state.cards.length===1?'card':'cards'
            const filteredCards = this.state.idToDelete && this.state.cards.filter(c=>c.id===this.state.idToDelete);  
            const warningCard = filteredCards[0] && filteredCards[0].name.toUpperCase();
            return(
                <div>

                    <button onClick={this.test}>test</button>
                    <button onClick={()=>this.setState({showForm:!this.state.showForm})}>form</button>
                    <button onClick={()=>this.setState({showEditForm:false})}>close edit from</button>

                    <h2>you have {this.state.cards.length} {card}</h2>

                    {this.state.showWarning && 
                    <div>
                        <h2>ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE THIS {warningCard} CARD?</h2>
                        <button onClick={()=>this.onConfirm(true)}>Yes</button>
                        <button onClick={()=>this.onConfirm(false)}>No</button>
                    </div>
                    }

                    {this.state.showForm &&
                        <CardForm
                        cardSave={this.onFormSubmit}
                        closeForm={this.onCloseForm}
                        />
                    }

                    {this.state.showEditForm &&
                        <CardForm
                        editCardSave={this.onEditCardSubmit}
                        cardToEdit={this.state.cardToEdit}
                        closeForm={this.onCloseForm}
                        editStatus={this.state.showEditForm}
                        />
                    }

                    <CardList
                        cards={this.state.cards}
                        cardClick={this.onCardClick}
                        deleteCard={this.deleteCard}
                        editCard={this.editCard}
                    />

                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default FlashCardMainPage
```

Comment: this is a very unsafe operation `this.state.cards.filter(c=>c.id===this.state.idToDelete)[0]`, because how do you know the result of filter won't be empty? So it is empty for some reason

Comment: it would be much easier to get into the problem if you could create a working example of you code here... https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: My app works well so far. All the cards updated and edited correctly. I just have one seemingly simple problem but it is giving me so much headache. I think the filter will not give me an empty array because the props is passed from a card in the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think some guards might help you here. What if you try changing the first line into two?

```
const filteredCards = this.state.idToDelete && this.state.cards.filter(c=>c.id===this.state.idToDelete);  
const warningCard = filteredCards[0] && filteredCards[0].name.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: I can confirm it works, I can confirm delete without error but there is one small problem, the first card never got the name show... can you please explain why your code works? really confused now and how can I have the first card name show?

Comment: Well, I don't think it's possible to answer this question without knowing more about the code, i.e. where does the idToDelete comes from, what is the structure of your cards and so on. If you could provide a reduce example in some sandbox, that could help.

Comment: As for the added code, it just checks that the array actually has a member, which name you are trying to get. That saves you from an error, because if the array is empty, it does not try to get the name.

Comment: I edited my question and included the full code in the bottom, but I am new so they are sloppy I afraid, but if you can please take a look, the idToDelete comes from a Card component and that props is passed to a different function, and I use that Id to setState idToDelete.

Comment: Thanks for the added code. If you could create a working example, using smth like https://stackblitz.com/ or alternative online solution, that would be even more helpful.